# Is the following series is converging, diverging, or?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is a fairly basic homework question so I'm not expecting a full answer but some hints would definitely be much appreciated.

Establish whether this series diverges, converges, or whether there is some sort of conditional convergence.

$$
\sum{\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n-2}}{n^\alpha}}
$$

How should I go about simplifying the above? And what convergence test should I look at?

Comment: Hint: Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n=2}$. Then comparison or limit comparison with appropriate series.

Comment: Oh right, and will have a conditional convergence of sort, as $\sum \frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1/2}}$ is converging/diverging depending on what value $\alpha$ takes. I think I got it, let me check it.

Comment: There is no conditional convergence issue, the terms are positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n-2}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2}}\in\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+2}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{n-2}}\right),$$
so the numerator behaves like $n^{-1/2}$.

Comment: So can I then say that the whole thing behaves like $\sum{\frac{1}{n^{\alpha + 1/2}}}$ which is the p-series which converges for $\alpha+1/2 > 1$ and diverges for $\le 1$? This is sort of where Andre Nicolas' comments above lead me but I'm not sure I'm properly phrasing this right.

Comment: @Alex: yes, exactly so.